# How to generate React table with different colored rows?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styling

I’m trying to create a React table in which each row is either gray or white. I am doing this by passing rows the props ‘gray’ or ‘white’ upon their creation, but in my MyRow class I’m not sure how to take this prop and convert it to a style.

Relevant code in MyTable.js:

```
    this.props.items.forEach(function(item) {
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
            rows.push(<MyRow item={item} key={item.name} color={'gray'} />);
        } else {
            rows.push(<MyRow item={item} key={item.name} color={'white'} />);
        }
        i++;
    }.bind(this));
```

MyRow.js render function:

```
render() {
    const color = this.props.color;

    const rowColor = {styles.color}; //?? I’m not sure how to do this—how to get color to take on either gray or white?

    return (
        <tr className={styles.rowColor}>
            <td className={styles.td}>{this.props.item.name}</td>
            <td className={styles.editButton}> <Button
                    onClick={this.handleEditButtonClicked}
                />
            </td>
        </tr>
    );
}
```

MyRow.css:

```
.td {
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.gray {
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
}

.white {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: If you already have the CSS classes defined, and you are passing the `className` as a prop, then just do `<tr className={rowColor}>`. Why are you piping `rowColor` through another object called `styles`. Where is `styles` defined? It's not included in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should be able to pass the prop directly to the row as follows, since it's already defined as a string in `MyTable.js` file:

```
render() {
    return (
        <tr className={this.props.color}>
            <td className={styles.td}>{this.props.item.name}</td>
            <td className={styles.editButton}> <Button
                    onClick={this.handleEditButtonClicked}
                />
            </td>
        </tr>
    );
}
```

Also, from the code you have posted, it's unclear where the `styles` object is located where you're trying to access these properties. If you wanted to access `styles.rowColor`, you would need a `styles` object defined:

```
const styles = {
    rowColor: color
};
```

Comment: My `styles` are defined in `styles.css`, and then I import styles into the js file.

Comment: I'm trying this now `<tr className={styles.this.props.color}>`, but getting the error "cannot read props of undefined"

Comment: Remove the `styles` from the beginning of that className and you shouldn't get any errors. `this.props.color`. Thanks for the clarification on the `styles` variables!

Comment: Hmm, but then how will I specify to look in the `styles` file for either gray or white? `this.props.color` is just pointing to "gray" or "white", which aren't defined in the js file and are rather accessed by styles.gray/styles.white

Comment: It seems like the missing piece from your question / code snippets above is that styles js file. From your original question, it seemed like the styles / className were just being associated with the CSS file posted. If not, provide that styles file instead.

Comment: You are correct, the styles/ className are associated with the CSS file posted, but ONLY when I import that CSS file into the js file (`import styles from './MyRow.css`). But, because I import the styles in this way, I need to precede any style with `styles.` in order to specify where the styles are defined. Sorry if that doesn't make sense, let me know if  I can clarify

Comment: Alright, so the issue right now is that your `MyTable.js` file is passing in each row with a color value that's a `string`. So `const color` is either the string `gray` or `white`, which can not be parsed into variables. A better bet would be to pass the style.color directly through. `<MyRow item={item} key={item.name} color={style.gray} />`. Then access the way I mentioned in my answer above. If that works, let me know and I can edit my answer to reflect that. Let me know if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this to change individual row cell color using row.value

```
{
  Header: () => <div className="text-center font-weight-bold">Status</div>,
  accessor: "selectedstatus",
  className: "font",
  width: 140,
  Cell: (row) => (
    <div
      className="text-center h-6"
      style={{ background: row.value === "Selected" ? "green" : "red" }}
    >
      {row.value}
    </div>
  ),
},
```